# Cannot access before initialization React Error

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, chart.js

I have got Cannot access 'chartjs' before initialization error when I want to run code. I am getting data from API, and want to create bar chart from using this API. But when I fetch this data and want to create chart.js required structure I get cannot access error.

```
import "./App.css";
import BarChart from "./components/BarChart";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [chartjs, setChartjs] = useState({
    labels: chartjs.data.map((item) => item.Year),
    datasets: [
      {
        labels: "Population",
        data: chartjs.data.map((item) => item.Population),
      },
    ],
  });

  const url =
    "https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setChartjs(response.data);
    });
  }, [url]);

  if (chartjs) {
    chartjs.data.map((item) => {
      console.log(item.Year);
    });
  }

  // const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
  //   labels: chartjs.data.map((item) => item.Year),
  //   datasets: [
  //     {
  //       labels: "Population",
  //       data: chartjs.data.map((item) => item.Population),
  //     },
  //   ],
  // });

  return (
    <div>
      <BarChart chartData={chartjs} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is BarChart.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {Chart as ChartJS} from "chart.js/auto"

const BarChart = ({chartData}) => {
    
  return <Bar data={chartData}/>;
};

export default BarChart;
```

Comment: where is chartjs defined ?

Comment: check useEffect section, I get data from API and write it with setChartjs

Comment: The initial state uses `chartjs` which is not defined, so is the error ....

Comment: how can I fix it ? Because I just tried to fix it with to define another useState, but it also didn't work

Comment: `chartjs` has to be defined with a proper structure you want and also I would give a different name to the state ....

Comment: can you edit this code if its not problem for you ? I am new for that type of things

Answer (score 0):

- you can keep the initial state as undefined (by default if nothing is provided)
- Make the structure you want before setting it to state from the API `response` ( I am not sure of the response structure but you can make it as you need)
- Added a loading state till the response is available (for demo purpose).

  ```
  function App() {
      const [chartjs, setChartjs] = useState();

      const url =
        "https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population";

      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
          const data = {
            labels: response.data.data.map((item) => item.Year),
            datasets: [
              {
                labels: "Population",
                data: response.data.data.map((item) => item.Population),
              },
            ],
          };
          setChartjs(data);
        });
      }, [url]);

      if(!chartjs) return "loading ...."

      return (
        <div>
          <BarChart chartData={chartjs} />
        </div>
      );
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I got this problem when I run your code : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.data.map is not a function

Comment: yeah like I said I'm not aware of the response structure....

Comment: thank you so much for editing my code, everything is clear for me right now :)